# I am unable to connect through SSH for Amazon WS EC2 on putty (server refuses our key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, putty

I have keypare abc.pem. I have public DNC. AMI is ubuntu.

I have generated private key (.ppk) file through puttygen using SSH1 and SSH2 both. and have tried both files but still getting error "server refuses our key".

I have searched on Stack Overflow and followed many links, also followed links from amazon forum, but still failed to connect.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You can only post once every 40 minutes. I guess it will take 40 minutes to put a question there. I have created account just now

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: If you do repost this question, please remove all the urgency - that does not belong in any post addressed to volunteers. Your question is not more important than that of anyone else.

Comment: Thanks guys the issue has been fixed.

thank you J.Garth. .pem file and I generated its private key .ppk file by using keygen. so there was encryption issue which was not matching. Now client has sent me correct file which hold private key.

Answer (score 1):

Try browsing for the .ppk file in the left hand menu under Connection --> SSH --> Auth

[image]

Comment: thank you J.Garth.

Actually the problem was that, client only sent me .pem file and I generated its private key .ppk file by using keygen. so there was encryption issue which was not matching. Now client has sent me correct file which hold private key. and its connected now through the same method which you have sent me the screenshot.